# How to get device last activity date in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a web application where one user can be authenticated in many devices in the same time. Each device sends its geo location coordinates to AWS API Gateway (AWS lambda function) every 30 seconds. The lambda function has to save coordinates to DB only from device which is authenticated later than the rest devices. Also lambda function has to ignore devices which has no activity for a long time.

For example user has 2 devices. If user is authenticated in device #1 two days ago, and the user is authenticated in device #2 today the lambda function has to save device #2 coordinates. But if device #2 had no activity for 3 hours (maybe this device is turned off) then the lambda has to save device #1 coordinates.

I'm trying to do it using Cognito User Pool with enabled "remember device" option:
[image]

Application signs in using Cognito Federated Identity and Cognito User Pool Authentication provider. Then every 30 seconds application sends HTTP request to AWS API Gateway (with AWS lambda function). Application passed "deviceKey" and "geoCoordinates" parameters to API method. The AWS lambda function gets all devices for current user using [AdminListDevices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminListDevices.html) method. Then AWS lambda is checking if current device is last authenticated using [DeviceLastAuthenticatedDate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DeviceType.html#CognitoUserPools-Type-DeviceType-DeviceLastAuthenticatedDate) property from AdminListDevices response.

The problem is that I don't know how to check the last activity date of the device (If device is turned off then there is no HTTP requests to the server, but Cognito remember this device for a long time). Maybe I could set lifetime of remembering the device? Or maybe there is a method to get last activity date of the device? Or maybe the application should change something in device and the Lambda will check the [DeviceLastModifiedDate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_DeviceType.html#CognitoUserPools-Type-DeviceType-DeviceLastModifiedDate) property?